# turning CSS on / off globally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My goal is to have a button (controlled by a javascript function) that would toggle the entire CSS on the website on and off. I thought this was a common practice and was surprised when I couldn't find a complete solution here or on the web.

Here is what I got.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var css = (document.styleSheets[0].enabled = true);
    if (css == true)
    {
        document.styleSheets[0].disabled = true;
        css =  (document.styleSheets[0].enabled = false);
    }
    else if (css == false)
    {
        document.styleSheets[0].disabled = false;
    }   
});
```

A simple Jquery function that targets the button by ID and performs an if test. I could've ommited the variable, but this way I am able to check the value easily in console.log. I am able to turn the CSS *off*, but not back *on*. The program doesn't even get to the else condition.
I am aware that the *else if* is not really appropriate, but with just else (and even just with another if condition) the function doesn't run at all.

Second option that I thought of, and which might be much easier is just dynamically changing the contents of the **link *href*** attribute, where the path to the css file is given.
But I am struggling to target the *href* element with Javascript.

Comment: Instead of using `.enabled` you should be modifying `.disabled`. So then: `css = document.styleSheets[0].disabled;` I should have written an answer; for clarification: `.enabled` is undefined, it does not exist, making its value true or false will not provide the desired result.

Comment: Just a couple of general tips: you may want to save `document.styleSheets[0]` in a variable such as `sheet` so you don't have to keep referencing it and give `css` a more descriptive name such as `cssEnabled`

Comment: Add `body.usecss` before all your css definitions and then just toggle that class.

Comment: dumb question.... what would be use case for ever needing to do this?

Comment: @charlietfl I would guess if the web page were designed in a way where CSS disabled would not completely obliterate cohesion of the displayed data/information then one possible idea is to use the resulting page for printing.

Comment: @charlietfl Case 1, debugging which stylesheet is causing some behaviour. Case 2, switching to a different layout, e.g. "night mode". Case 3, pretending there are multiple pages on one page without having too much active _CSS_ floating around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple *Boolean* toggle so write it as a simple toggle

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
    sheet.disabled = !sheet.disabled;
});
```

---

As for why your code isn't working as is,

```
var css = (document.styleSheets[0].enabled = true);
// same as
var css;
document.styleSheets[0].enabled = true;
css = true;
```

which means

```
if (css == true)
// same as
if (true == true)
```

which always holds so you'll always follow this code path

Comment: the boolean toggle is so damn easy and convenient. I wasn't familiar with the function before. Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are doing an assignment when you should be doing an equality check.

You have

```
var css = (document.styleSheets[0].enabled = true);
```

But you are really trying to do an equality check, i.e.,

```
var css = (document.styleSheets[0].enabled == true);
```

Notice the extra `=`. The single `=` does an assignment, so your current code is equivalent to this:

```
document.styleSheets[0].enabled = true
var css = document.styleSheets[0].enabled; // i.e., true
```

Because you set enabled to `true`, your `if (css == true)` condition is always satisfied, so your code always turns the CSS off and never turns it back on.

The fix, as Paul S. wrote in his answer, is just to toggle the value of `document.styleSheets[0].disabled`, as in:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    document.styleSheets[0].disabled = !document.styleSheets[0].disabled;
});
```

There's no need to set and track a new property `enabled`.

Comment: Just thought I'd point out a _CSSStyleSheet_ doesn't have a native property called _enabled_, in my answer I toggle _disabled_

Comment: @PaulS. Indeed. You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. I upvoted your answer, as it is excellent.

Comment: thank you. This was indeed a stupid mistake... but all the answers here helped me to clarify a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one you need to loop through all of the stylesheets.

Also, you can save some lines of code by using a counter, then on each button click increment the counter and use the `%` modulo operator to turn that into a 1 or a 0, which you can then coerce a boolean from using `!!`.

```js
var count = 0;
var sheets = document.styleSheets;

$("#button").click(function() {
    for(var i in Object.keys(sheets)) sheets[i].disabled = !!(++count % 2);
});
```

```css
.demo {
  background: #888;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo">Some Text</div>
<button id="button">Click It</button>
```

Comment: `Object.keys` will give an _Array_, you should be looping with `for`, not `for..in`

Comment: Yeah no, for...in loops are perfectly fine for use with an array unless you are using some stupidly designed framework that extends the native array object's prototype. In which case I would much rather find out that the framework is garbage ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you are doing assignment, and not comparison, on this line:

```
var css = (document.styleSheets[0].enabled = true);
```

It should be

```
var css = (document.styleSheets[0].enabled == true);
```

Probably simpler, since you have a jquery tag on the question, to just do:

```
$stylesheets = $('link[rel="stylesheet"]');
$("#button").click(function() {
    $stylesheets.attr('disabled', !$stylesheets.attr('disabled'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify every href in your DOM,

just use

```
 $('a[href*=]').each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.attr('href', $this.attr('href').replace();
            });
```